Capture Java Main Class Output in Spring Boot and Display in Angular
I have a Java Main class in a Spring Boot project that generates output when run. It needs to work both independently via the CLI and through a Spring Boot controller. When I input values via a form on the frontend, I want to run the Main class with those inputs, capture its output, and display it in real-time in a logs container on the Angular frontend.
Here are the Angular component's HTML and TypeScript files, along with the Java Main class and the Spring Boot controller.
Frontend(Angular)
admin-dashboard.component.html
<div class="dashboard-header"></div>

<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="form-container">
    <h2>Enter Values</h2>
    <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
      <label for="totalTickets">Total Tickets:</label>
      <input type="number" id="totalTickets" [(ngModel)]="totalTickets" name="totalTickets" required>

      <label for="ticketReleaseRate">Ticket Release Rate:</label>
      <input type="number" id="ticketReleaseRate" [(ngModel)]="ticketReleaseRate" name="ticketReleaseRate" required>

      <label for="customerRetrievalRate">Customer Retrieval Rate:</label>
      <input type="number" id="customerRetrievalRate" [(ngModel)]="customerRetrievalRate" name="customerRetrievalRate" required>

      <label for="maxTicketCapacity">Maximum Ticket Capacity:</label>
      <input type="number" id="maxTicketCapacity" [(ngModel)]="maxTicketCapacity" name="maxTicketCapacity" required>

      <button type="submit">Start</button>
      <button type="button" (click)="stop()">Stop</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="logs-container">
    <h2>Logs</h2>
    <div class="logs">
      <div *ngFor="let log of logs">{{ log }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

admin-dashboard.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './admin-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class AdminDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  totalTickets: number = 500;
  ticketReleaseRate: number = 123;
  customerRetrievalRate: number = 43;
  maxTicketCapacity: number = 2;

  // For storing logs
  logs: string[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/api/ticketing/config')
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.totalTickets = response.totalTickets || 500;
        this.ticketReleaseRate = response.ticketReleaseRate || 123;
        this.customerRetrievalRate = response.customerRetrievalRate || 43;
        this.maxTicketCapacity = response.maxTicketCapacity || 2;
      });
  }

  // For submitting the form data to the backend
  submitForm(): void {
    const formData = {
      totalTickets: this.totalTickets,
      ticketReleaseRate: this.ticketReleaseRate,
      customerRetrievalRate: this.customerRetrievalRate,
      maxTicketCapacity: this.maxTicketCapacity
    };

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/ticketing/config', formData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.logs.push('Configuration updated successfully!');
        console.log('Form Submitted:', response);
      }, error => {
        this.logs.push('Error updating configuration');
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }

  // For stopping the process
  stop(): void {
    console.log('Booking process stopped');
    this.logs.push('Booking process stopped');
  }
}

Java (needs to run separately in the CLI while also having its output displayed on the frontend)
Main class
package com.oop.Springboot.ticketingcli;

public class Main {

    public static void runTicketingProcess(Configuration config) {
        int totalTickets = config.getTotalTickets();
        int ticketReleaseRate = config.getTicketReleaseRate();
        int customerRetrievalRate = config.getCustomerRetrievalRate();
        int maxCapacity = config.getMaxTicketCapacity();

        TicketPool ticketPool = new TicketPool(maxCapacity);

        // Create vendor threads to add tickets to the pool
        for (int i = 0; i < ticketReleaseRate; i++) {
            int vendorId = i + 1;
            Vendor vendor = new Vendor(vendorId, ticketPool, totalTickets, ticketReleaseRate);
            Thread vendorThread = new Thread(vendor);
            vendorThread.start();
        }

        // Create customer threads to book tickets from the pool
        for (int i = 0; i < customerRetrievalRate; i++) {
            int customerId = i + 1;
            Customer customer = new Customer(customerId, ticketPool, 1000);
            Thread customerThread = new Thread(customer);
            customerThread.start();
        }
    }

    // Main method for running the application as a standalone Java app
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a sample configuration for testing
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setTotalTickets(100);
        config.setTicketReleaseRate(10);
        config.setCustomerRetrievalRate(5);
        config.setMaxTicketCapacity(50);

        // Run the ticketing process with the sample configuration
        runTicketingProcess(config);
    }
}


Controller class
package com.oop.Springboot.controller;

import com.oop.Springboot.ticketingcli.Configuration;
import com.oop.Springboot.ticketingcli.Main;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/ticketing")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200" , allowedHeaders = "*")
public class TicketingController {

    private Configuration config;

    public TicketingController() {
        this.config = new Configuration();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/config")
    public String updateConfig(@RequestBody Configuration newConfig) {
        this.config.setTotalTickets(newConfig.getTotalTickets());
        this.config.setTicketReleaseRate(newConfig.getTicketReleaseRate());
        this.config.setCustomerRetrievalRate(newConfig.getCustomerRetrievalRate());
        this.config.setMaxTicketCapacity(newConfig.getMaxTicketCapacity());
        
        Main.runTicketingProcess(config);
        return "Configuration updated successfully!";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/config")
    public Configuration getConfig() {
        return this.config;
    }
}

What should I add to make this work?
I tried integrating a Java Main class in a Spring Boot project to produce real-time output and send it to an Angular frontend. The goal was to input values through a form and display the output in a logs container in real-time.
However, I am encountering the following issues:
Error in Logs Container: When the "Start" button is clicked, the logs container displays the message:
"Error updating configuration".

Console Error: I’m getting the following error in the browser's console:
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 403,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/ticketing/config",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/api/ticketing/config: 403 OK",
    "error": null
}

do I need to use database?

I solved the problem
